# RPC call failed

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

When I run my project I get the error message "RPC call failed." which would be from my LoginView class AuthenticationHandler class. Also, the window alert in the ClickHandler is displaying the values entered into the page of "aa/bb". The MySQL and Tomcat are started and I have tried to ensure all drivers are installed by following numerous online guides and forums. However, I suspect that I have not got something right in this respect. However, I could be wrong. Can some one please let me know what to check and how to fix it. Details would be appreciated as I am a newbie.

I "Run as" Web application and GAE is not enabled (I mention this as I found this was the cause in another question). I have a MySQL database award tracker with a user of DBuser and password DBpass setup with one table with data in it.

The error log has my displayed message "Error connecting to database - not good eh" that I inserted in my MySQLConnection class. Below is the log and the classes:

Console:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/awardtracker
Error connecting to database - not good eh
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection.<init>(MySQLConnection.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Starting Jetty on port 8888
[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract org.AwardTracker.client.User org.AwardTracker.client.DBConnection.authenticateUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection.authenticateUser(MySQLConnection.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 22 more
[ERROR] 500 - POST /org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/MySQLConnection (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
Request headers
  Accept: */*
  X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
  X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/
  Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/AwardTracker.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
  Accept-Language: en-au
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; MAAU)
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
  Content-Length: 199
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Cache-Control: no-cache
Response headers
  Content-Type: text/plain
```

DBConnection class

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

/**
 * The client side stub for the RPC service.
 */
public interface DBConnection extends RemoteService {
public User authenticateUser(String user, String pass);
}
```

User class

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class User implements IsSerializable {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String username;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String password;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private User() {
    //just here because GWT wants it.
}
public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

LoginView class

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;


import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PasswordTextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget;

public class LoginView extends Composite {
private TextBox textBoxUsername;
private PasswordTextBox passwordTextBox;

private DBConnectionAsync rpc;

public LoginView(final NavHandler navHandler) {

    rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    initWidget(verticalPanel);

    Label lblWelcomeToThe = new Label("Welcome to the Award Tracker login page");
    lblWelcomeToThe.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    verticalPanel.add(lblWelcomeToThe);

    Label lblSignInTo = new Label("Please sign in to your account");
    lblSignInTo.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    verticalPanel.add(lblSignInTo);

    FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
    verticalPanel.add(flexTable);

    Label lblUserName = new Label("Username:");
    lblUserName.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, lblUserName);
    lblUserName.setHeight("12px");

    textBoxUsername = new TextBox();
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, textBoxUsername);

    Label lblNewLabel = new Label("Password:");
    lblNewLabel.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 0, lblNewLabel);

    passwordTextBox = new PasswordTextBox();
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 1, passwordTextBox);

    CheckBox chckbxRememberMeOn = new CheckBox("Remember me on this computer");
    chckbxRememberMeOn.setStyleName("gwt-Checkbox-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 1, chckbxRememberMeOn);

    Button btnSignIn = new Button("Sign In");
    btnSignIn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (textBoxUsername.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Window.alert("Username is empty."); 
                }else if (passwordTextBox.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Window.alert("Password is empty."); 
                }else {
                    AsyncCallback<User> callback = new AuthenticationHandler<User>();
                    Window.alert(textBoxUsername.getText() + "/" + passwordTextBox.getText());
                    rpc.authenticateUser(textBoxUsername.getText(), passwordTextBox.getText(), callback);
                }
        }
        class AuthenticationHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<User> {
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                Window.alert("RPC call failed.");   
            }
            public void onSuccess(User result) {
                navHandler.go("SelectPerson");
            }
        }
    });
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 1, btnSignIn);

    Label lblCreateAcct = new Label("Create an account");
    lblCreateAcct.setStyleName("gwt-Link-Login");
    lblCreateAcct.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            navHandler.go("CreateAccount");
        }
    });
    flexTable.setWidget(4, 1, lblCreateAcct);
}

}
```

MySQLConnection class

```
package org.AwardTracker.server;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

import org.AwardTracker.client.DBConnection;
import org.AwardTracker.client.User;

public class MySQLConnection extends RemoteServiceServlet implements DBConnection {
private Connection conn = null;
private String status;
private String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker/";
private String user = "DBuser";
private String pass = "DBpass";
public MySQLConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //NEVER catch exceptions like this
        System.out.println("Error connecting to database - not good eh");
    }
}

public User authenticateUser(String userName, String pass) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "select readonly * from at_accounts where acc_email_address = \"" + userName  + "\" AND " + "acc_password = \"" + pass + "\"");
      result = ps.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
         user = new User(result.getString(1), result.getString(2));
      }
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException 1.");
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return user;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to look at the

```
MySQLConnection "private String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker/";"
```

the jbdc should be jdbc.

Answer (score 1):

The String of database url seems wrong.you with out database prot.

```
private String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker/";
```

change to this if your database use default prot:

```
 private String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/awardtracker/";
```

Comment: Hi zhongying, Sorry this did not work. Also, I do not know what I have done but I no longer have my Server tab in Eclipse. I used to select that tab to start the server. This time I had to start the server from Windows for this test. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: click "Window" in Eclipse toolbar,select "show view",then select the  tab you need to open. :)

Comment: Thank you zhongying, I now have my server tab back. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi zhongying, I retried your change of adding :3306 and it does not work. Any other ideas? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I have received advice to add "e.printStackTrace();" after my first message. I have updated the logg above. In short I have the message "No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/awardtracker". I have followed all instructions and installed drivers so where should I look? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Did you add  the JAR file named  "mysql-connector-java-5.1.8.jar" into your project?

Comment: And add it to project's build path.

Comment: Hi zhongying, The answer is [drim role please] ... look at the MySQLConnection "private String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker/";" the jbdc should be jdbc. Thank you for your help. Regards, Glyn.